# multiple and single selection of div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have multiple div in a container.

- I have a select all button on top and 3 divs with an ok button inside the container.
- If I click "select all" button, I should select all the divs inside.
- If I click on any div inside of the container, only the particular div should get unselect. Now everything is getting unselected.
- If I click select all button i need to pass all three divs in a parameter (i.e selectAll(div1,div2,div3)).
- After clicking selectall ok button will get hide and the only div will show. If I click the selected any div that particular div should get unselect.
  (i.e if I select the second div, div2 should get unselect and first and thirst still should be select)
- I don't want to use $index because I have multiple divs inside. I have a unique id for each div. I want to pass that id.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqdm615c/3/)

```js
function MainCtrl($scope) {
   
   $scope.containerSelected = false;
   $scope.buttonVisible = true;
   $scope.toggleButton = function (e) {
   
   console.log('toggleButton')
       $scope.containerSelected = true;
       $scope.buttonVisible = false;
       e.stopPropagation();
    };
   
    $scope.toggleContainer = function (e) {
    console.log('toggleContainer', $scope.containerSelected)
       if($scope.containerSelected){
           $scope.containerSelected = false;
           $scope.buttonVisible = true;
       }
    };
    
};
```

```css
#myApp{
  width:100%;
  display:-webkit-inline-box;
  border :1px solid black;
  margin-top:55px;
}
.container{
  width:10%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:10%;
}
button.btn.btn-primary{
  margin-top:25%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
.selectedBorder{
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#selectALL{
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div  title="Angular Scope" ng-app ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <button id="selectALL" ng-click="toggleButton($event)">Select All</button> 
 <div id="myApp">
 

<div class="container" ng-class="{ 'selectedBorder': containerSelected }" ng-click="toggleContainer()">
<button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleButton($event)" ng-show="buttonVisible">ok</button> 
</div>
<div class="container" ng-class="{ 'selectedBorder': containerSelected }" ng-click="toggleContainer()">
<button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleButton($event)" ng-show="buttonVisible">ok</button> 
</div>
<div class="container" ng-class="{ 'selectedBorder': containerSelected }" ng-click="toggleContainer()">
<button id="okBtn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleButton($event)" ng-show="buttonVisible">ok</button> 
</div>

</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: is there always 3 divs?

Comment: No. It will more 100 also.

Comment: So it will be better if you use `ng-repeat` with `$index`.

Comment: i dont want $index. Because I have a unique id for each div. I want to pass that unique ID. Here I have mentioned right div1,div2,div3 like this.

Comment: Can you please edit it in jsfiddle

Comment: you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/045uvmh1/1/